# subprocess.Popen does not run a program

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd

I want to launch a command line program from my Python script. I'm working on Windows 10 with Python 3.6. The following code launches command line, but doesn't print anything. (If I print 'echo hi' in this command line window, it works fine).

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(['cmd','echo','hi'])
```

If I try

```
p=subprocess.check_call(['cmd','echo','hi'])
```

I get `CalledProcessError: Command '['cmd', 'echo', 'hi']' returned non-zero exit status 3221225786.`

If I try `p=subprocess.check_call(['echo','hi'])`, I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` message.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(["call", "cmd", "/k", "echo Hello"], shell=True)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("Error")
```

Meaning:

`call` - call the shell within the python executable

`cmd` - open the command line window

`/k` - Run Command and then return to the `cmd`prompt (basically, means hold the `cmd` window

If you want to start the everything in new shell, replace `call` with `start` keyword in args.

**For more flags:** run `cmd /?` in the cmd prompt.

**Note:** It is a good programming to put the methods or function calls within error handling blocks like `try-except-finally`.